# How to save the contents of all opened tabs in Chrome automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

Suppose I'm doing some research and I've got open few Chrome windows with a lot of tabs and I need to close the browser or some part of tabs and someday bring them 
back but I know the contents (like Google search results or YT related) that I would like to see again will change. How can I prevent it or how to save all the 
contents of all or just selected tabs automatically? Due to the amount of tabs, doing it manually would last too long. Saying save I mean taking a snapshot, copying 
all selected text contents, downloading a page in some form or eventually storing its source. Is there any easy to use solution or any appropriate extension for that?
I can't find anything useful and all ways I tried to force Chrome to not reload pages after start don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chromium Scrapbook](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-scrapbook/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb) (also available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/)) should do what you're looking for.

Comment: as of now probably called WebScrapBook